# Printing z3 expressions using the python api

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I am trying to use z3 to simplify a few expressions generated by S2E/KLEE

```
from z3 import *

f = open("query.smt2").read()
expr = parse_smt2_string(f)

print(expr)
print(simplify(expr))
```

But it seems to only log 200 lines. I have also tried writing it to file, but that has the same result.

```
g = open("simplified_query.smt2", 'w')
g.write(str(simplify(expr)))
g.close();
```

How should I log the entire expression?

Example input/output: https://paste.ee/p/tRwxQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print the expressions using the Python pretty printer as you do. It cuts off the expressions if they become very big and the pretty printer is not efficient. There are settings you can add to the pretty printer to force it to print full expressions. The function is called set_pp_option and it is defined in z3printer.py. The main option is called max_depth. Other options are defined as fields in the Formatter class.

You can also print expressions in SMT2 format using the method "sexpr()".

BTW, the file you uploaded doesn't process because it is in UTF8 format, but this is orthogonal to your question and probably an artifact of how you uploaded the repro.